# Lyx 2.3.6.1 on windows 11 does not show IPE preview

Tags: lyx, windows, ipe

In Lyx 2.3.6 under windows 11, the IPE preview does no longer appear, while it did so in windows 10. All other types of figures appear.
What I tested:

1. The ipe convertors work when called from the command line, with the
   same files as used in the lyx.
2. The ipe figures do appear in the pdf output, only the lyx preview is
   missing.
3. The security settings on the IPE folder and Lyx folder match those of the other applications
4. There are no weird characters in the pathnames
5. Starting Lyx from the command line in debug mode does not show any output

Any help is appreciated, seeing the figures is much more informative!

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue in the end. It was related to the usage of quotes in the filename of the iperender.exe convertor used to convert ipe to png. Adding the path in the lyx paths variable and removing the quotes solved the issue.